# Is NextPage necessary when building NextJS apps in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In the nextJS examples, specifically the example showing how to use TypeScript with NextJS, they don't use the NextPage type.

The file I'm talking about is here:  https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/blob/master/typescript-final/pages/posts/%5Bid%5D.tsx and the relevant code is this:

```
export default function Post({
  postData
 }: {
    postData: {
    title: string
    date: string
    contentHtml: string
  }
 }) {
   return (...
```

I'd think that it could be written like this:

```
export default function Post : NextPage<Props> ({
  postData
 }: {
    postData: {
    title: string
    date: string
    contentHtml: string
  }
 }) {
   return (...
```

or something similar.

My question is, I can't find any doc's in the NextJS site on using the imported interface NextPage, and specifically, the next team left it out of their documentation.

Should I be using NextPage?

Comment: _Should I be using `NextPage`?_:  If you prefer explicitly stating the return type then you should. If you want to automatically deduce the `postData` type then also you should. Besides, there are many things that are not available on the docs. Better check their discussions, someone would have discussed similar thing(s).

Answer (score 12):

Both is ok. It's just a type.

If you add the `NextPage<Props>`, then the type declaration in parameter is not necessary. You can simplify it as

```js
export default function Post : NextPage<Props> ({ postData }) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking there are other benefits (like requiring a return), but not 100% sure

Comment: This style of typing throws errors for me. Is this currently supported in TypeScript?

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid code.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be using NextPage?

NextPage is the type of the return, and Props is the type of the argument to the function.

`Post : NextPage<Props>`

I would include both, as although these can be interpreted by TS it is better to explicitly state them - some linters have rules which enforce their inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

`NextPage` is a type exported by the Next.js framework, which is a React-based server-side rendering (SSR) framework for building web applications. It is a type alias for a React component that includes a getInitialProps function that is used for fetching data needed for server-side rendering.

When defining a page component in Next.js, it is recommended to use the `NextPage` type from the next package instead of defining your own interface or type. This helps to ensure compatibility with Next.js and provides helpful type checking and auto-completion support in code editors.

See this example below, `HomePage` is a `NextPage` component that takes in a Props object and includes a getInitialProps function that fetches some data and returns it as props.

```
import { NextPage } from "next";

type Props = {
  title: string;
};

const HomePage: NextPage<Props> = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my home page!</p>
    </div>
  );
};

HomePage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  // fetch some data here
  return { title: "My Home Page" };
};

export default HomePage;
```