# What are the benefits of using the NextPage type in page components with Next.js 14 and beyond?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, types, next.js13, next.js14

I was wondering if it's necessary to use the NextPage type in Next.js version 14 and beyond for page components, especially when utilizing the App Router. Does it significantly enhance type safety? I'm interested in understanding the best practices in this context. Additionally, I'm curious about how the App Router might influence its usage. Thank you in advance.

Given that in Next.js versions 14 or higher, we move away from using getInitialProps and getServerSideProps, I'm considering the implications of this change. What are the benefits of using the NextPage type in this new context?

I've searched for an answer on various forums but couldn't find a clear explanation. Additionally, the documentation on the Next.js website doesn't provide clear guidance on this subject.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027985/is-nextpage-necessary-when-building-nextjs-apps-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027985/is-nextpage-necessary-when-building-nextjs-apps-in-typescript)